# Error en busqueda con Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-6

Desde un input quiero escribir el nombre de un empleado y si coincide con un registro de la base de datos poner su información en la vista. al intentar cargar la vista me manda el error de que la variable empleados no está definida

Función del controlador

```
public function buscarEmpleados(Request $request){
  
    $empleados = Empleados::where('nombre','like','%'.$request->nombre.'%')->get();
     return \View::make('list', compact('empleados'));
```

}

Ruta

```
Route::post('registrar/buscarEmpleados', ['as' => 'registrar/buscarEmpleados', 'uses'=>'EmpleadosController@buscarEmpleados']);
```

Vista

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <form method="POST" action="{{url('/buscarEmpleados')}}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                                </td>
                                <td>    
                                    <input  id="nombre" name="nombre" >
                                </td>
                            </tr> 
                           <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <input type="submit"  name="buscar" value="Buscar">
                                </td>
                           </tr>
                         </form>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Titulo</th>
                            <th>Carrera</th>
                            <th>Departamento</th>
                            
                        </tr>
                       @foreach($empleados as $empleado)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $empleado->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $empleado->nombre }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $empleado->apellidoP }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $empleado->apellidoM }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $empleado->titulo}}</td>
                            
                        </tr>
                       @endforeach
```

Error en pantalla
Variable indefinida: empleado (Vista: C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ plantilla \ plantilla \ recursos \ vistas \ horarios \ registro.blade.php)
Excepciones anteriores
Variable indefinida: empleado (0)

Comment: Tienes un *typo* pues en el `foreach` declaras esto `empleado` y luego tratas de usar esto: `$empleado`, solo te faltó el símbolo de dólar. Derivado de lo anterior he de comentarte que tu pregunta quedará cerrada

Comment: Eso fue un detalle que se me pasó al escribir la pregunta, una disculpa ya lo corregí pero realmente no es ese el problea

Comment: El código que expones no tiene error alguno, usas esa variable en algún otro lado?

Comment: No, solo la estoy utilizando ahí